How to disable the default context menu, but still be able to select text in react native?
How to disable the default context menu, but still be able to select text in react native?
I want to select text in a React Native app to perform other operations, but the default context menu behavior is causing problems by opening when I try to perform my actions.

Please update your question to include more information. What does your code look like? what have your tried already? etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
